# what if i have only one document and i want to get vectors of all sentences using doc2vec

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am new to python and machine learning. I have a file(kkk.csv). this has 101 sentences 1 sentence per line . I want to get each sentence's vector using Doc2vec in gensim. After that i want to use those vectors to perform clustering so that same sentences will group together. Can someone please provide me code for this(getting vectors for each sentence and clustring them)?

i tried with this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
#from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import gensim,logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', 
level=logging.INFO)
from os import listdir

docLabels = []
docLabels = [f for f in listdir('''C:/Users/rekhasharma/new''') if 
f.endswith('.csv')]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('''C:/Users/rekhasharma/kkk.csv''',names = ['comments'])

rows = 100
df = df.iloc[:rows]
list1 = df.values.tolist()
del list1[0]

class LabeledLineSentence(object):
    def __init__(self, doc_list, labels_list):
       self.labels_list = labels_list
       self.doc_list = doc_list
    def __iter__(self):
       for idx,doc in enumerate(self.doc_list):
           yield gensim.models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(doc,self.labels_list)
it = LabeledLineSentence(list1, docLabels)
model = gensim.models.Doc2Vec(vector_size=50, min_count=0, alpha=0.025, 
min_alpha=0.025)
model.build_vocab(it)

for epoch in range(100):
    print ('iteration' + str(epoch+1))
    model.train(it,total_examples=49, total_words=None, epochs=1)
    model.alpha = 0.002
    model.min_alpha = model.alpha

model.save('doc2vec.model')
d2v_model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec.load('doc2vec.model')

docvec = d2v_model.docvecs[0]
print (docvec)
```

Comment: What Did you try?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example for your question. refer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Shubham i added my code

Answer (score 0):

Just use gensim's official documentation ([link](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html)), tutorial ([link](https://rare-technologies.com/doc2vec-tutorial/)) and then their official example notebooks on doc2vec:

- [Lee](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-lee.ipynb)
- [IMDB](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-IMDB.ipynb)
- [Wiki](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-wikipedia.ipynb)

If you go through these and some things are still unclear to you, feel free to write a more **specific** question

Comment: Hi how to reproduce the sentence from given vector in doc2vec??

Comment: Please tell me how to use these sentence vectors to do clustering so that similar sentences may be grouped together